# WPF video player finishes with last rendered frame still showing

Tags: wpf, libvlcsharp

I have created a simple WPF video player using VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows 3.0.18 and LibVLCSharp.WPF 3.7.0. The video plays as I would expect it to, but when the video ends the last rendered frame remains in the VideoView control. If I stop the video while it is playing the VideoView control goes blank which is what I think should happen when the video ends.

This is the code behind for the stop button

```
    private void StopMediaPlayer()
    {
        if (_mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (_mediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
            {
                _mediaPlayer.Stop();
            }
        }
        _vm.MediaPlaying = false;

        if (_fileStream != null)
        {
            _fileStream.Close();
            _fileStream.Dispose();
            _fileStream = null;
        }
    }
```

I would think that the EndReached event should be doing something but I don't see anything for it to do.